# create multidimetional array associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$arr = array(
1=>'xyz',
2=>'abc',
3=>'pqr'
);
```

I want to convert this to

```
$multiarr=array(
[0]=>array(
    ['id']=>1,
    ['name']=>'abc'),

[1]=>array(
    ['id']=>2,
    ['name']=>'xyz'),

[2]=>array(
    ['id']=>3,
    ['name']=>'pqr')

);
```

id is key and the name is the value of the first array

how can I implement this optimistically

I have done this

```
$keys=array_keys($arr);
$values=array_values($arr) ;   
$multiarr=array();
for($i=0; $i<count($keys); $i++)
{
 $multiarr[$i]['id']=$keys[$i];
    $multiarr[$i]['name']=$values[$i];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `array_walk($arr,function($val,$key) {return array('id'=>$key,'name'=>$val);});` after that for fresh index do `$arr=array_values($arr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should really be trying this yourself mate, but this should help:

```
$arr = array(
    1=>'xyz',
    2=>'abc',
    3=>'pqr'
);

$MultiArr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $ID=>$Name){
    $MultiArr[$i]['id'] = $ID;
    $MultiArr[$i]['name'] = $Name;
    $i++;
}
print_r($MultiArr);
```

Comment: @Epodax duly noted. Although he has provided his starting code, just giving the chap a point in the right direction.

Comment: @mokNathal try the provided answer

Comment: @mokNathal and if it solves your problem, please accept the answer